# How to reorder TabBar's Tabs programmatically?

Tags: ios, xcode, tabbar

Is there a way to reorder tabs of a TabBar programmatically on xCode?

Thank you a lot, Matteo!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

   tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

   MyViewController* vc1 = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
   MyOtherViewController* vc2 = [[MyOtherViewController alloc] init];

   NSArray* controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc1, vc2, nil];
   tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;

  // Add the tab bar controller's current view as a subview of the window
  [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
 }
```

Comment: This is a code of adding UITabbarcontroller. It will not *reorder the tabs* which questioner has asked.

Comment: This code of course does it but as as I have understood he is asking about reordering tabs with dragging them.

Comment: question appears to be vague. but if the question is about re-odering tabs by dragging, I would advise against it.

Comment: With "programmatically" I mean with code. I'd like that my App opening, checks a device setting and it order following a condition; I mean: App starts -> check a system parameter", for example "has user setted an email account?" -> if yes order tabs in order 1, 2, 3 else order tabs in order 3, 2, 1. I don't know what can i put in if condition to order tabs...